# In the first Ace Attorney game, why aren't Edgeworth and von Karma in custody for making up evidence?

Tags: phoenix-wright-ace-attorney

I just finished the first Phoenix Wright: Ace Attorney game yesterday and, while I really enjoyed my experience, there has been something bugging me during my entire playthrough.

It is stated by Wright early on that Edgeworth "would do any thing to get a guilty verdict". While this sentence alone seems fishy, as it seems to imply more than plain determination, I let it slip first. However, we quickly learn that Edgeworth influences witnesses and cover up/make up evidence and testimonies to head the trial in the direction he wants. I cannot provide screenshots of the exact wording but these facts come out pretty clear and are repeated multiple times by Phoenix, both out loud and in his mind.
To further prove my point, in the "Turnabout Samurais" chapter, after her cross-examination, Ms Oldbag says out loud, in the Courtroom, that the prosecutor had told her not to testify about a specific matter. 
Also, during the "Turnabout Sisters" chapter, for example, Edgeworth already knows that there were more than a witness and that Mia Fey was being spied on by April May, but he does not tell the Court about that matter and instead, lets Wright discover and prove that fact with evidence.

If we now cast our attention on von Karma, there is information revealed in a piece of dialogue during the final minutes of the game which I found rather puzzling. It is explained that the outcome of a trial, with Edgeworth's father as the Defense, and von Karma as the Prosecution, was a guilty verdict for the defendant. Now, the game tells us that the Defense rose an objection regarding the falsification of evidences by the Prosecution. We then learn that the Court acknowledged the objection and penalized von Karma, but that the guilty verdict stood. During the "Turnabout Goodbyes" chapter, von Karma quite clearly stuns both Wright and Maya to steal all of the evidence regarding the DL-6 case from the Police storage room, but apparently no one objects to this as if he could.

My question is, why aren't Miles Edgeworth and von Karma in prison for having made up evidence for years, since this fact is apparently acknowledged by many?

Comment: Well if I remember well Von Karma does end up in prison. But if you keep up with that mentality you're not gonna enjoy the rest of the games because that happens quite a lot ^^'

Comment: The AA series never seems to mind much whenever an attorney withholds information or coerces a witness to do so. What *does* get penalized, however, is *forging evidence*. It's likely that Von Karma forged evidence by putting the defendant's fingerprints on some vital piece of evidence, and *that's* what he got penalized for. But since he still managed to prove the defendant's guilt without that particular piece of evidence, the verdict was still "guilty".

Comment: Note that later games retconned it so Edgeworth never forges evidence.  In fact, Edgeworth even stars in two of his own games, although the second never got an English release.  It did get a fan translation, though...

Comment: One thing that should be noted is that this is never addressed in-game, making it impossible to answer as a lore based question, and therefore off-topic.  This is a game of poke the plot hole.